# Badge Icon Bug when Viewing From Other Site

Tags: bug, badges

So I was looking at a badge that I got awarded on the dropdown menu whilst browsing Biology SE. The badge was a popular question one from Law SE. The badge symbol displayed was the DNA helix that is used on Biology SE rather than the icon used on Law SE. I believe this is confusing and should probably be considered a bug.

[image: Bug]